# Übersetzung für "random"

Tags: translation

Ich suche eine gute Übersetzung für

> That answer was somewhat random

Wie ist die folgende?

> Die Antwort war recht zufällig/willkürlich.

Sagt man das so?

Comment: http://youtu.be/ESPRTHo9oTk?t=2m1s

Comment: The problem with this question is that it's not a good use of the word "random" even in English. A better way to say it in English would be 'the answer was something of a non-sequitur'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es gibt leider nicht die eine gute Übersetzung für "random".

**"Willkürlich"**

Das passt, wenn Wille involviert ist. Ein Ereignis kann zum Beispiel nicht "willkürlich" sein, wohl aber "random". Im Kontext von "Antwort" finde ich, dass es eine gewissen Ignoranz des Antwortenden impliziert.

**"zufällig"**

Das passt meiner Ansicht nach nicht so gut in die Satzstruktur.

> Etwas war zufällig.

Ich würde hier eher sagen "Zufall" oder "zufällig + noch etwas"

**"beliebig"**

"Beliebig" drückt in erster Linie die Idee von "any" aus (pick any card), es wird aber auch für Sachen verwendet, die nicht so ganz zur Situation passen.

> some random dress
>   ein x-beliebiges Kleid

**unerwartet oder komisch**

Die können auch passen, da sie die Überraschung die in "random" steckt, einfangen.

> Oh, that was random.

Ohne Kontext ist es, denke ich, unmöglich zu entscheiden, welches Wort in deinem Beispiel passt.

Comment: Das mit dem Willen bei Willkürlich würde ich noch ausbauen: `willkürlich` bedeutet, willentlich auf eine Regelantwort zu verzichten. Man könnte die richtige Antwort finden, verzichtet aber aus Ignoranz darauf und wählt stattdessen *zufällig* eine der gegebenen Antworten aus. In `zufällig` steckt stattdessen keine Information über die Hintergründe.

Answer (score 13):

Eine recht gut passende Wendung, die mir dazu spontan einfällt, ist auch:

> Diese Antwort scheint ein wenig **aus der Luft gegriffen**.

Comment: Gute Idee, wobei das ein wenig in Richtung "far fetched" geht.

Comment: ...zu 'far fetched' würde man meistens 'weit hergeholt' sagen.

Comment: When we were growing up we always thought "verfetscht" was perfectly good Yiddish.

Answer (score 8):

Ich würde diese Version bevorzugen.

> Die Antwort war recht willkürlich

Ich denke, *zufällig* passt bezogen auf eine Antwort nicht. Das kommt auf den Kontext an, ohne weitere Informationen dazu würde ich *willkürlich* verwenden.

---

Edit: Kontextabhängig wäre *beiläufig* auch denkbar. Siehe [Duden: beiläufig #1](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beilaeufig#Bedeutung1)

Answer (score 2):

Anfangs fiel mir da nichts Rechtes ein. Jetzt kommt mir eine Idee. Manche Leute sagen da: "Ach, das hab ich so aus dem Bauch heraus gesagt" oder "Ich hab nach Bauchgefühl geantwortet, ich hab da nicht lange überlegt".

Oder: Das ist mir so spontan gekommen, ich habe da nicht lange überlegt.