# Irgendeine und Beliebige: Words for "any"

Tags: difference

In a card game (called [Magic: The Gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) if you know it), a [card (Birds of Paradise)](http://magiccards.info/m12/de/165.html) has the following ability:

> - Erhöhe deinen Manavorrat um ein Mana einer beliebigen Farbe
> - Add one mana of any color to your mana pool.

How is *beliebige* different from *irgendeine*?

I read in [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11920/13847) that *beliebige* simply means "any" (the example was "pick any card"), but that's the same translation for *irgendeine*. Are they simply synonyms or are there special context rules?

---

In einem Kartenspiel ([Magic: The Gathering](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering)) hat eine [Kreatur](http://magiccards.info/m12/de/165.html) die folgende Fähigkeit:

> Erhöhe deinen Manavorrat um ein Mana einer beliebigen Farbe

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *beliebige* und *irgendeine*?

Ich habe [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11920/13847) gelesen, dass *beliebige* auf Englisch "any" lautet (das Beispiel war "pick any card"), aber das ist auch die Übersetzung von *irgendeine*. Sind diese Wörter Synonyme oder hängt es von dem Kontext ab?

Comment: Both words basically mean the same i.e. _any_; however, _beliebige_ is a more formal way of conveying the meaning of _any_. It means something like _as you please_, _wie es dir beliebt_, _nach deinem Belieben_.

Comment: @jera y u no proper answer?

Comment: Related http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23239/why-does-beliebig-mean-random-while-belieben-suggests-the-contrary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is minute, yet crucial:

*Any colour* translated as *irgendeine Farbe* is correct and so is *beliebige Farbe*.

The difference is the method of choice: *irgendeine* is a bit unclear about how the colour is chosen (dice throw?) and has more of a "randomness", *beliebig* means the player chooses a colour *of his choice* - in the context of the game usually something that suits their strategy.

As I said, they are *almost* synonymous, especially in a colloquial use, the difference adds a tad more clarification which is useful in a game like MtG.

Comment: Does this randomness also apply to other _irgend-_ words such as _irgendwo_?

Comment: Full ack, and in addition, I feel that _irgendeine_ takes a lower word quality rank than _beliebige_. The latter feels more classy and high-level.

Comment: Jup, @hiergiltdiestfu, the register is different.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu what does "ack" mean?

Comment: @Arc676 http://www.drsl.de/wiki/index.php?wasist=ACK

Comment: Ich kenne niemanden, der einen Würfel werfen würde, wenn er eine beliebige Farbe wählen sollte, außer mich selbst, vielleicht. Insofern sehe ich das crucial sehr critical. Gedanklich spiele ich schon mit einem Downvote.

Answer (score 2):

"Irgendeine" refers to "any" chosen at *random,* e.g. by the roll of dice.

"Beliebige" refers to "any" chosen at *discretion.* You are making a decision.

In your example, "Add one mana of any color to your mana pool," the correct word would be beliebige, because you are playing Magic, a game involving strategy, more than chance. On the other hand, if you were playing Monopoly, and were asked to draw "any" *Chance* or *Community Chest* card, the right word would be irgendeine (Karte).