# Difference between "Jed-" and "Beliebig"

Tags: word-choice

The root word "jed-" (as in jede, jedes, etc.) and the word "beliebig" both mean "any." What is their difference in usage?

Comment: jede/jeder/jedes = every; beliebig = arbitrary

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich jeder/jede/jedes can also be _each_.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29733/irgendeine-und-beliebige-words-for-any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We say, there are 5 numbers from 1 to 5 on the blackboard

1  2  3  4  5

when I say you that you should remove **each** number on the list.

> Bitte entferne jede Nummer in der Liste.

You would remove each number and the result would be as follows;

<del>1</del>  <del>2</del>  <del>3</del>  <del>4</del>  <del>5</del>

However, when I say that you should remove a number in the list on your choice.

> Bitte wähle eine beliebige Nummer aus und entferne sie.

it means that it does not matter for me, which number you will choose to remove. You can remove 1 or 2 or 3 ... etc.

For instance, you have chosen 2 and the result is as follows;

1  <del>2</del>  3  4  5

Comment: I don't think the second part is right. Please see this related question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29733/irgendeine-und-beliebige-words-for-any. I believe that "beliebig" would be as a matter of "choice," not "randomly" (closing your eyes). Please double check; it's possible I may be wrong.

Comment: @TomAu I have researched about this "randomness" and based on the examples on the internet, I can say that you are right. Thanks for the tip. I have editted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hier sind Beispielsätze, die den Gebrauch von *jede/r/s* und *beliebige/r/s* demonstrieren.

> A: Was für ein Eis möchtest du?
>
> B: Ich möchte von **jeder Sorte** eine Kugel!
>
> A: Herrje! Und du?
>
> C: Ich möchte eine Kugel von einer **beliebigen Sorte**!
>
> A: Das ist schon besser!

B bekommt - wenn der freche Wunsch denn erfüllt wird - in einer gut sortierten Eisdiele ein Riesenhörnchen mit 20 Kugeln Eis. C bekommt ein Hörnchen mit nur einer Kugel Eis, punktet dafür aber mit Bescheidenheit und damit, dass er/sie nicht wählerisch ist.